# Make Magento e-mails work for Google "My Purchases"

Tags: search, seo, transactional-mail, google-analytics

About: Make Magento e-mails work for Google "My Purchases"

Yesterday I was browsing one of our products that we sell via our brand site, but also some platforms. Suddenly I saw a recent purchase in my Google search overview. What? Apparently [this is not new](http://www.itworld.com/article/2854974/google-can-now-show-your-your-latest-purchases-via-google-search.html) but I did not read how to get it working for our order e-mails.

https://www.google.nl/search?q=my+purchases

**Question:** so how would one add this to the Magento transactional e-mails?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this google "feature" is more based on email contents search/indexing than meta-tags or another mail format thing.

In this picture you can see (at last position) a test purchase that was placed in an fresh magento install

[image]

Actually the algorithm isn't precise at all two o this four results are not actual transactions.

So don't worry about that google will spy your emails data in order to show you your purchases without asking nothing.

BTW in other results I see some purchases that I did more than 4 years ago (on ebay) I guess that for some cases just is looking for the email address.